# Pandas extensive 'describe' include count the null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame composed of 450 columns with 550 000 rows.
In the columns i have :

- 73 float columns
- 30 columns dates
- remainder columns in object

I would like to make a description of my variables, but not only describe as usual, but also include other descriptions in the same matrix. At the final, we will have a matrix of description with the set of 450 variables then a detailed description of:
- dtype
- count
- count null values
- % number of null values
- max
- min
- 50%
- 75%
- 25%
- ......

For now, i have juste a basic function that describe my data like this :

```
Dataframe.describe(include = 'all')
```

Do you have a function or method to do this more extensive descrition.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you need min and max and quantile for object > - <

Comment: No not for object

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need write custom functions for `Series` and then add to final describe `DataFrame`:

*Notice*:

*First row of final df is `count` - used function [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for count non NaNs values*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,np.nan,np.nan,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A    B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4.0  7  1  5  a
1  b  NaN  8  3  3  a
2  c  NaN  9  5  6  a
3  d  5.0  4  7  9  b
4  e  5.0  2  1  2  b
5  f  4.0  3  0  4  b
```

---

```
df1 = df.describe(include = 'all')

df1.loc['dtype'] = df.dtypes
df1.loc['size'] = len(df)
df1.loc['% count'] = df.isnull().mean()

print (df1)
              A         B        C        D        E       F
count         6         4        6        6        6       6
unique        6       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       2
top           e       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       b
freq          1       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       3
mean        NaN       4.5      5.5  2.83333  4.83333     NaN
std         NaN   0.57735  2.88097  2.71416  2.48328     NaN
min         NaN         4        2        0        2     NaN
25%         NaN         4     3.25        1     3.25     NaN
50%         NaN       4.5      5.5        2      4.5     NaN
75%         NaN         5     7.75      4.5     5.75     NaN
max         NaN         5        9        7        9     NaN
dtype    object   float64    int64    int64    int64  object
size          6         6        6        6        6       6
% count       0  0.333333        0        0        0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, there is no alternative function to `describe()`, but it clearly isn't displaying all the values that you need. You can use various parameters of the `describe()` function accordingly.

`describe()` on a DataFrame only works for numeric types. If you think you have a numeric variable and it doesn't show up in `describe()`, change the type with:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].astype(float)
```

You could also create new columns for handling the numeric part of a mixed-type column, or convert strings to numbers using a dictionary and the `map()` function.

`describe()` on a non-numeric Series will give you some statistics (like count, unique and the most frequently-occurring value).

To call `describe()` on just the `object`s (strings) use `describe(include = ['O'])`.